# Autofac Registration Brace

Tags: c#, ioc-container, autofac, orchardcms

In the last days I took a watch to the orchad source, and in the bootstrap class during the registration of the components with Autofac I saw same code that I can't explain!!!!
I will provide an example:

```
builder.RegisterType<A>().As<IA>();
{
  builder.RegisterType<B>().As<IB>();
  {
     builder.RegisterType<C>().As<IC>();
  }
}
```

I can't undstand what the brace do? Is it like a sub registration??

Hope somebody can help me!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gabe! English is not my language!! Thank

Comment: This has nothing to do with Autofac. It's a c# thing. As ROBOLav said, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @steven you are right! Sorry i didn't know that!

Comment: No need to apologize ;-)

Comment: I believe that it's there only to have the IDE indent the code to make it a bit easier to read. It's grouping certain things together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be no different than writing:

```
builder.RegisterType<A>().As<IA>();
builder.RegisterType<B>().As<IB>();
builder.RegisterType<C>().As<IC>();
```

Surrounding something with braces creates a different context, e.g:

```
int a = 1;
{
    int b = 2;
}
// b not accessible from here
```

In your case, the function doesn't seem to return anything, and therefore, context doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yup, it's just a simple hack to have the IDE do intenting to make things more readable